# Accept two answers

Tags: support, acceptable-answer, answers

I accepted one answer and attempted to accept another as complementing, but that removed #1's acceptance, so I reverted back to accept #1's answer. Will the second answer receive notification of apporoved answer despite it being changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this depends on the time between them - I have tried to check but I think the notifier runs reasonably frequently but not continuously, so assuming you changed it back before the next check there should be no notification.

If you are wanting to reward two answers, you have earned the [Set Bounty](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) privilege, which will allow you to give some of your rep as a reward for a good answer - and it doesn't have to be the accepted answer, or even on your own question.